# Classification of Huge number of classes

Tags: classification, oversampling

I have a dataset of samples belonging to >100 classes. I want to classify and/or cluster these classes. I have the following questions:

1) Is one classifier efficient for such problem? or one classifier for each one/subset of classes? (From my point of view: the efficient solution is to discover the features discriminate each class from all others and solve the problem as 1-to-all classification problem. Any suggestion on that?)

2) About 60% of these classes have 1 or 2 samples at maximum!. How can I create new samples from these 1-sample classes. Do you think any of SMOTE (synthetic minority oversampling technique) techniques are workable in this case.

Regards,

Comment: that's not a task for classification. You want to use Poisson (or even the usual LS) regression here.

Comment: @user603 Why would those models apply?

Answer (score 6):

More than 100 classes shouldn't be a problem for most classification algorithms. However, if that number increases you should start thinking about new models for large-scale (in this case for the number of classes) classification. You can probably find some hint in this (a bit old) workshop about [large-scale (hierarchical) text classification](http://lshtc.iit.demokritos.gr/workshop).

About the number of elements within classes, 1 or 2 elements is way too low. Based on my experience you need at least 10-20 examples per class, although this is dependent on several conditions such as type of data and collection.

To get new examples for some of the classes, have you considered some type of (semi-)manual labelling of documents to expand your training set?

I hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For that many classes and classes with very few samples, I would try triplet loss.
For every sample, choose other of same class and other from another class, train with the goal to minimize the distance from samples of same class while maximizing the distance between samples of classes.
You create a cluster space where classes separate from each other, and can be used even for many classes and very few samples of each class.